# LIKE-Query with PHP, mySQL and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, backslash, apostrophe

I want to match `\'` in my a column in a table in a MySQL Database, because these are entries where the data wasn't properly escaped.

I use PHP with PDO, this is the relevant code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE :title");
$stmt->bindValue(':title',"%\\'%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Problem is, this matches titles with `\'` as well with a single '. I tried various combinations of `\\\\\'` etc., but nothing really worked to just match `\'`, not the single `'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ... or just wrap it into single quotes (instead of double ones).

Comment: As a matter of fact, it would help to see what the query looks like when it gets passed to the database.

Comment: raina77ow: `$stmt->bindValue(':title','%\\\'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);` does match \' and ' as well.
Matt: As far as I know, there is no way to see the raw query generated from PDO, or is it?

Comment: @tholu, uncomment/add `log` to your `my.ini` then restart `mysqld`. Now you'll see all the queries in `mysql/data/HOST_NAME.log`

Comment: Query looks just like that (when wrapping in single quotes): `SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%\\\'%'` - yet, it selects titles with `\'` and `'` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you actually need to do this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':title',"%\\\\\\'%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

That is 6 backslashes and one apostrophe which then matches one backslash and one apostrophe. Anyone got an explanation for this?

PS: I don't know why just adding backslashes didn't work before, I tried that, seems like I had double quotes or something.